# Conversion of convex QCQP to standard form SDP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, qcqp, linear-matrix-inequality

I have the following QCQP:

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x}}{minimize} \quad \mathbf{x}^{T} H \mathbf{x}  + \mathbf{p}^{T} \mathbf{x}$$
$$ subject \; to \quad \mathbf{x}^{T}Q_{i}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{x} + r_{i} \leq 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, p $$

Where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I convert it into an SDP as follows. The first step is to rewrite in epigraph form:

$$ {minimize} \quad \delta $$
$$ subject \; to \quad  \mathbf{x}^{T} H \mathbf{x}  + \mathbf{p}^{T} \mathbf{x} \leq \delta$$
$$ \quad \mathbf{x}^{T}Q_{i}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{x} + r_{i} \leq 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, p$$

Since $H$ is PSD, we can take its Cholesky factorization, giving us $H = \tilde{H}^{T}\tilde{H}$. Defining $\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = [\delta, \mathbf{x}]^{T}$ The first constraint can therefore be written as:

$$
G(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{n} & \tilde{H} \mathbf{x} \\
(\tilde{H} \mathbf{x})^{T} & \delta - \mathbf{p}^{T}\mathbf{x}
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$

Similarly, $Q_{i} = \tilde{Q_{i}}^{T}\tilde{Q_{i}}$ the other equations can be written as:
$$
F_{i}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{n} & \tilde{Q_{i}} \mathbf{x} \\
(\tilde{Q_{i}} \mathbf{x})^{T} & -\mathbf{q_{i}}^{T}\mathbf{x} - r_{i}
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$

So we can put all of these together, and write:

$$
 E(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) = diag\{ G(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}), F_{1}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}), \ldots, F_{p}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}})\} \geq 0
$$

So we get the SDP problem:

If we let $\mathbf{\tilde{c}} =[1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0]^{T}$ then clearly, $\delta = \mathbf{\tilde{c}}^{T} \mathbf{\tilde{x}}$

$$ \underset{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}{minimize} \quad \mathbf{\tilde{c}}^{T} \mathbf{\tilde{x}}$$
$$ subject \; to \quad E(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \geq 0$$

What I am stuck with is how to convert that into something of the form:

$$ \underset{X}{minimize} \quad trace(CX)$$
$$ subject \; to \quad trace(A_{i} X) = b_{i}  \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, p$$
$$  X \geq 0$$

How can I do this? Is it even possible?

---

**My attempt at a solution, following the suggestions in the comments:**

The first step is to convert all the LMI matrices into LMIs proper. To do so, we notice that we can convert an LMI matrix:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  I_{n} & A \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b} \\
  (A \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b})^{T} & \mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x} + d
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
\end{equation}

Into the LMI equation $F_{0} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} x_{j} F_{j} \geq 0$ by:

\begin{equation}
 F_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}
  I_{n} & \mathbf{b} \\
  \mathbf{b}^{T} & d
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 F_{j} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{a}_{j} \\
  \mathbf{a}_{j}^{T} & c_{j}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{a}_{j}$ is the $j$th column of $A$, and $c_{j}$ is the $j$th element of $\mathbf{c}$.

So lets apply that to each LMI matrix. First up is $G(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \geq 0$. This gives us:

\begin{equation}
 G_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}
  I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} \\
  \mathbf{0}_{n}^{T} & \delta
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 G_{j} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{\tilde{h}}_{j} \\
  \mathbf{\tilde{h}}_{j}^{T} & -p_{j}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{\tilde{h}}_{j}$ is the $j$th column of $\tilde{H}$, and $p_{j}$ is the $j$th element of $\mathbf{p}$. Therefore, for $G(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \geq 0$, we have $G_{0} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} x_{j} G_{j} \geq 0$.

Next up are the $F_{i}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \geq 0$. We have now:

\begin{equation}
 F_{i_{0}} = \begin{bmatrix}
  I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} \\
  \mathbf{0}_{n}^{T} & -r_{i}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 F_{i_{j}} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{\tilde{q}}_{i_{j}} \\
  \mathbf{\tilde{q}}_{i_{j}}^{T} & q_{i_{j}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{\tilde{q}}_{i_{j}}$ is the $j$th column of $\tilde{Q}_{i}$, and $q_{i_{j}}$ is the $j$th element of $\mathbf{q}_{i}$. Therefore, for $F_{i}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \geq 0$, we have $F_{i_{0}} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} x_{j} F_{i_{j}} \geq 0$. So we put this together, to get:

\begin{align}
 minimize& \quad \mathbf{\tilde{c}}^{T} \mathbf{\tilde{x}} \nonumber \\
 subject \; to& \quad G_{0} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} x_{j} G_{j} \geq 0 \nonumber \\
     & \quad F_{i_{0}} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} x_{j} F_{i_{j}} \geq 0 \quad i=1,2,\ldots p \nonumber \\
\end{align}

Now the dual of this function can be obtained by letting:

\begin{align}
 \mathbf{\tilde{y}} &= -\mathbf{\tilde{x}} \nonumber \\ 
 \mathbf{\tilde{b}} &= \mathbf{\tilde{c}} \nonumber \\ 
 C_{0} &= G_{0} \nonumber \\ 
 A_{j} &= G_{j} \nonumber \\ 
 C_{i_{0}} &= F_{i_{0}} \nonumber \\ 
 A_{i_{j}} &= F_{i_{j}} \nonumber \\ 
\end{align}

Which gives us:

\begin{align}
 maximize & \quad \mathbf{\tilde{b}}^{T} \mathbf{\tilde{y}} \nonumber \\
 subject \; to& \quad C_{0} - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} A_{j} \geq 0 \nonumber \\
     & \quad C_{i_{0}} - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} A_{i_{j}} \geq 0 \quad i=1,2,\ldots p \nonumber \\
\end{align}

Adding a slack matrix gives us:

\begin{align}
 maximize & \quad \mathbf{\tilde{b}}^{T} \mathbf{\tilde{y}} \nonumber \\
 subject \; to& \quad \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} A_{j} + S_{0} = C_{0} \nonumber \\
     & \quad \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} A_{i_{j}} + S_{i_{0}} = C_{i_{0}}  \quad i=1,2,\ldots p \nonumber \\
\end{align}

And this is where I am currently getting lost. How can I construct my matrix $X$? Is the matrix $C$ equal to $C_{0}$? Also, how do I fit in my $b_{i}$ in the primal? Is my derivation even correct so far?

---

**Following Johnan Loefburg's article 'Dualize it: software for automatic primal and dual conversions of conic programs' I get:**

$$A(X) = [trace(A_{1}X), trace(A_{2}X), \ldots, trace(A_{N}X), trace(A_{1_{1}} X), trace(A_{1_{2}}X), \ldots, trace(A_{1_{N}}X), trace(A_{2_{1}}X), \ldots, trace(A_{p_{1}}X), \ldots, trace(A_{p_{N}}X)]^{T} $$
$$C = C_{0} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} C_{i_{0}} $$
$$b = [\delta \mathbb{1}_{N}^{T}, \tilde{b}_{1}\mathbb{1}_{N}^{T}, \ldots, \tilde{b}_{N}\mathbb{1}_{N}^{T}]^{T} $$

I get:

$$ minimize \quad trace(CX) $$
$$ subject \; to \quad A(X) = b$$
$$ X \geq 0$$

What do you think? Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: What is the dual of your SDP?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285881/91764).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have edited my answer to reflect my progress using your suggestions, however, now I am stuck at a new point. Am I correct so far? Any further suggestions or advice or answers?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Please see my comment to Rodrigo. Any advice?

Comment: max $b^Ty $ subject to $C-A^Ty\succeq 0$ is effectively in the form min $\text{trace}~CX$ subject to $AX = b, X\succeq 0$ since these are the primal-dual pairs that SDP solvers solve (given $C, A,b$, the solver computes $y$ and $X$).

Comment: BTW, I hope this is only an exercise for fun and learning, because you would never do this in practice. Instead, you would solve the problem in the original quadratic (or SOCP) form

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I understand the equivalence you state, but here, I have multiple $C$ matrices. I am not sure how to handle the multiple $C$ matrix case.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I am only trying to understand how one converts a QCQP to an SDP. You are saying that in practice, I should find a solver that can solve QCQPs directly, right? But, how would those solvers solve the QCQP then? By converting it to an SOCP?

Comment: Yes, QCQPs would be converted to SOCP.

Comment: The theory generalizes to multiple constraints (corresponding to several cone variables $X_i$ in the primal). The naive way of doing that generalization is that you simply create a large SDP by placing all constraints in a block-diagonal matrix. The paper referenced here (by me) https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/automaticdualization/ might shed some light on what I am saying

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I edited my answer to reflect your comment and reference. Am I correct or did I miss something?

Comment: Well, that depends what the actual goal is. You have not written the original problem in standard primal form, but simply noticed that when you write your problem in standard dual form, if someone asks you for the data $A,b,C$ to solve a problem to to compute the solution to your QCQP, and that person thinks you are working in the primal space, you will give that data, and ask the person to please return both $X$ and $y$ from the solver.  to be continued...

Comment: continued..The person thinks $X$ is the important variable, as he thinks you've formulated the problem in that space, but the important variable for you is really $y$. You can write your problem directly in the primal space (having $X$ actually mean something related to the QCPQ), but it would lead to an inefficient way to represent the QCQP)